# Error during installing postgers 12 in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, postgresql

I'm installing Postgres 12 on my Ubuntu 12 system, I get the error when trying to run many different commands :

```
sudo apt -y install postgresql-12
sudo apt  install postgresql-12
```

Here is my error output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-11 : Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, I cannot copy/paste from your picture to look up answers/suggestions for you (thus you can copy/paste the detail yourself into http://packages.ubuntu.com/ if you wish).  You also mention Ubuntu 12 OS; I think a typo.

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu. It is prefered to paste the contents of terminal output as text formatted as code.

Comment: Hi @TejasLotlikar, i've modified my question and put the image content as a text

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql-12`? `libicu60` is available from official repositories. What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Hi @Kulfy, i've solved the issue, by  upgrade instead off update, thank you

Comment: Great!!! You might consider to add what you did as answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg` file, change `bionic` to `eoan`.

use:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ eoan-pgdg main
```

instead of:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open `terminal`

Step 2:Run the command

```
sudo apt clean
```

Step 3: Update the package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 4: Remove all files from `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` (if exists)

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Step 5: Update package list, install dependency and install PostgreSQL

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libicu60 
sudo apt install postgresql-12
```

Comment: when i try to install "libicu60", i got this error :      Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu60 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu60' has no installation candidate